# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when executing a build inside an update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I am getting a pesky ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError, and I can't find how to fix it.

I was following this guide:
https://rbudiharso.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/dynamically-add-and-remove-input-field-in-rails-without-javascript/
and everything works great except when I am updating the record.

My controller:

```
if params[:add_item]
  # rebuild the baixa_itens attributes that doesn't have an id
  unless params[:baixa][:baixa_itens_attributes].blank?
    for attribute in params[:baixa][:baixa_itens_attributes]
      @baixa.baixa_itens.build(attribute.last.except(:_destroy)) unless attribute.last.has_key?(:id)
    end

(...)

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def baixa_params
      params.require(:baixa).permit(:prontuarios_id, :data, :profissional_id, :comentario, baixa_itens_attributes: [ :id, :item_id, :quantidade, :preco, :_destroy ])
    end
end
```

When I got my crash, I tested it in the console:

```
>> attribute
=> ["1", {"item_id"=>"3", "quantidade"=>"1", "preco"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"0"}]
>> attribute.last.except(:_destroy)
=> {"item_id"=>"3", "quantidade"=>"1", "preco"=>"1"}
>> @baixa.baixa_itens.build(attribute.last.except(:_destroy))
!! #<ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError>
```

But if I try to make this build MANUALLY, it works:

```
>> @baixa.baixa_itens.build({"item_id"=>"3", "quantidade"=>"1", "preco"=>"1"})
=> #<BaixaItem id: nil, baixa_id: 6, item_id: 3, quantidade: 1, preco: #<BigDecimal:7ff97147b6f8,'0.1E1',9(18)>, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I workaround this problem doing

```
for attribute in params[:baixa][:baixa_itens_attributes].permit!
```

in my controler (not using ! would give me error: "Unpermitted parameters: 0, 1", which i cant understand)

I still wish a better solution.